# Reading firestore data with dynamic path

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I have changed my firestore rules to make the data readable by the owner my rules are below -

```
service cloud.firestore {
match /databases/{database}/documents {
       match /users/defaultmenuItems {
          allow read: if request.auth != null;
          allow write: if false;
        }

        match /users/{userId} {
          allow read,update,write: if isOwner(userId); 
        } 

        function isOwner(userId) {
          return request.auth.uid == userId;
        }
    } 
}
```

I have problem reading the values with dynamic path. I don't know why it is not working?

```
firebaseFirestore.collection("users")
                .document(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid() + "/"+dynamic_path)
                .get()
                .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DocumentSnapshot> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                            DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot = task.getResult();
                            if (documentSnapshot.exists()) { 
                                Log.d(TAG, "Found Document");
                            } else {
                                getDeafaultItems(path);
                                Log.d(TAG, "Default");
                            }
                        } else {
                            Log.d(TAG, "Sorry ....");
                        }
                    }
                }); 
    }
```

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to accomplish with `dynamic_path`.  Your rules allow a user to read a document in users with their own UID.  That's what your document path must be.  Anything else will fail.  Please edit the question to explain in more detail what you're hoping to do here.

Comment: dynamic path is the name of the nested document/collection. something like  uid/vegitables or uid/fruits or uid/drinks. It was working before when I had default read write rules.  when I made them user specific, they stopped working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your rules do not allow any access to subcollections nested under the user document.  You will either need to call out each subcollection individually and allow access to it:

```
match /users/{userId} {
  allow read,update,write: if isOwner(userId); 
} 

match /users/{userId}/fruits {
  allow read,update,write: if isOwner(userId); 
}
```

Or use a recursive wildcard to match all possible documents in all possible subcollections:

```
match /users/{userId} {
  allow read,update,write: if isOwner(userId); 
} 

match /users/{userId}/{document=**} {
  allow read,update,write: if isOwner(userId); 
}
```

I suggest reading more about recursive wildcards in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-structure#recursive_wildcards).

Comment: I am getting this error ... DocumentSnapshot{key=users/QwnbAEE992Z1MAJkFOoJy4BUGzk1/fruits/berries, metadata=SnapshotMetadata{hasPendingWrites=false, isFromCache=false}, doc=null}

Comment: fixed the error. dont worry. : ) thanks for the help